# Shows color if true red in text, if false then red after assertion using selenium any one having solution?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

How to shows color if true green in text, if false then red after assertion using selenium any one having solution?

```
if(patientname.equals("Roma Fg")) { 
    Assert.assertEquals(patientname, "Roma Fg"); 
    Reporter.log("Patientname is verified:" +patientname); 
} else { 
     Assert.assertNotSame(patientname, "DD g"); 
     Reporter.log("Patientname is not verified:" +patientname); 
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to see the colored text? Are you using any report module? Allure Reports?

Comment: What's a `Reporter`?

Comment: Yes testng report.